# Сравнение Func<T, TResult> на равенство. C#

Tags: c#, делегаты

Подскажите как нужно проверить следующий момент:

В методе есть параметр `Func<Объект класса, object> predicate`.
В методе есть ветвление в зависимости от того, какой предикат буде передан. И в этом же методе я пытаюсь написать следующее:

```
// Предикат, равенство которому влияет на ветвление в методе
Func<Объект класса, string> func = здесь выбор нужного поля класса(к примеру, s => s.Name). 

// Пытаюсь сравнить предикат из аргумента и func(это не правильно, как правильно не догоняю)
if (predicate.Equals(func))
{
    flag = true;
}
```

Подскажите как это нужно делать?

Comment: Никак. Две ссылки на методы будут равны, только если это один и тот же метод.

Comment: @Igor а проверить на равенство через поле, на которое эти методы ссылаются тоже нельзя?

Comment: Мб можно как-нибудь через выражения это дело раскрутить, а какая цель? Возможно решение изначально подбирается неверное.

Comment: @yolosora, есть класс, у которого среди прочих полей есть string result. В result есть данные в качестве оценки "9", "5" и "Сдал", "Не сдал". Когда этот тип нужно отсортировать по полю result, то есть специальный компаратор(мною написанный). Так вот этот компаратор нужно кидать в метод OrderBy(IEnumerable<T>) только в том случае, если в предикате указано поле result, в остальных - работает дефолтный OrderBy(IEnumerable<T>), куда я передаю предикат из аргумента.

Comment: Есть решение использовать перечисление для того, чтобы дать возможность выбрать необходимое поле  для сортировки. Но тогда будет больше кода. А так это очень удобно, но не понятно, как в этой ситуации поступать.

Comment: Хотя стоп, можно через "провал" в switch'е избежать дублирование. Сейчас попоробую.

Comment: Зачем вам "компаратор" для `OrderBy`? Я лично это не могу понять... И почему у вас оценки в виде `string`, когда это число?

Comment: Оценки могут быть как числом, так и фразой: "Сдал" или "Не сдал". Можно сказать это не оценки, а результат. Компаратор нужен специально для того,чтобы нужным образом отсортировать коллекцию по этому полю

Comment: Подумайте логически, как может стоять оценка, если человек не сдал работу? То есть можно смело делать `int Score` и если `Score == default`, то "Не сдал", если же `Score != default`, то работа сдана и в `Score` у нас оценка. Если оценка может быть `0`, то можно сделать `int? Score`, тогда `default == null`. Так что у вас тут неверно проработана архитектура приложения, из за которой вы сейчас лепите костыли.

Comment: Тут можно всё объектами делать, и предикат, чтоб их сравнивать, и/или оценку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сравнение делегатов работает следующим образом: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.delegate.equals?view=netcore-3.1

> - If the two methods being compared are both static and are the same method on the same class, the methods are considered equal and the
>   targets are also considered equal.
> - If the two methods being compared are instance methods and are the same method on the same object, the methods are considered equal and
>   the targets are also considered equal.
> - Otherwise, the methods are not considered to be equal and the targets are also not considered to be equal.

Увы, два разных лямбда выражения вида `s => s.Name`, даже если в коде они идентичны, представляются в бинарнике разными анонимными методами, так что сравнение делегатов работать не будет.

Но если методы делают одно и то же, должен же быть способ выяснить это, иными словами, сравнить методы "по значению"? Да, такой способ есть. Так как лямбда-метод - это одиночное выражение, ни блоков обработки исключений, ни локальных переменных в нем быть не может, равенство таких методов, по сути, сводится к побайтовому равенству их IL-кода. Это приводит нас к такому способу сравнения:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

public class Person
{
    public string Name;
    public string Location;
}

class Program
{
    static bool AreMethodsEqual(MethodBase left, MethodBase right)
    {
        MethodBody m1 = left.GetMethodBody();
        MethodBody m2 = right.GetMethodBody();
        byte[] il1 = m1.GetILAsByteArray();
        byte[] il2 = m2.GetILAsByteArray();
        return il1.SequenceEqual(il2);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Func<Person, string> func = s => s.Name;
        Func<Person, string> predicate = x => x.Name;
        
        Console.WriteLine("Результат сравнения делегатов: "+func.Equals(predicate));
        Console.WriteLine("Результат сравнения методов:   "+AreMethodsEqual(func.Method, predicate.Method));

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Но этот способ работает только для предикатов, полученных из лямбда-выражений, заданных на этапе разработки. Если оно генерируется динамически на основе LINQ Expression, AreMethodsEqual не сработает, так как GetMethodBody выдаст исключение.

Comment: Большое спасибо за развернутый овтет.